# ¿Como saber que un arreglo tiene la misma cantidad consecutiva de 1’s y 0’s?

Tags: python, array, binario

ayuda
Desarrollar una función en Python que dado un arreglo de 0s y 1s devuelva un valor de 1 si es que existe la misma cantidad consecutiva de 1s y 0s; en caso de que no se cumpla la función retornará un 0. Por ejemplo:
0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1 (tenemos un 0 y un 1, luego 0,0,0 y luego 1,1,1) retornará 1, esto porque tiene la misma cantidad consecutiva de 0s y 1s.
111 retornará 0, este valor se retorna porque le faltaría contener tres ceros consecutivos.
1,1,0,0,1,0 retornará 1.
(tratar que tenga la menor cantidad instrucciones y sea sencillo, no como el mío)

```
def binars(a,n):
 c=0
 i=0
 bs=True
 while(i<n and bs==True):
  k=1-1//(n-i)
  if(a[i]==a[0]):
    c=c*((1-a[i-c])*(1-2*a[0])+a[0])+1
  if(a[i] != a[0] and a[(i+1)*k]==a[i+1-c]. or a[n-1]==a[0]):
    bs=False
  i=i+1
 print(bs) 
a=[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0]
binars(a,len(a))
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es la pregunta?

Comment: El enunciado dice: **Desarrollar una función en C**, pero en tu pregunta muestras código de Python. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver el problema creamos una función que retorne True si se cumple la condición.

Esta función recibe un *iterable*, que puede ser una cadena, una lista, etc.

```
def check(lista):
    n = 0
    if lista:
        inc = 1
        prev = lista[0]
        for bit in lista:
            if bit != prev:
                inc = -inc
                prev = bit
            n += inc
    return n == 0
```

El método es simple. En `n` llevamos la cuenta de cuantos bit iguales hemos visto. Primero vamos sumando 1 con cada bit igual. Al cambiar el bit, vamos restando 1. Esto lo hacemos cambiando el valor de `inc` de +1 a -1. Asi, alternando entre sumar y restar, al final debemos obtener cero si la condición se cumple.

Si terminamos el ciclo iterativo con `n == 0`, el argumento cumple la condición.

#### Demo

```
def check(lista):
    n = 0
    if lista:
        inc = 1
        prev = lista[0]
        for bit in lista:
            if bit != prev:
                inc = -inc
                prev = bit
            n += inc
    return n == 0

tests = [
    "",
    "0",
    "00",
    "0101",
    "0001",
    "010011000111",
    "0011010100001111"
]

for test in tests:
    resultado = check(test)
    print(test, resultado)
```

produce

```
 True
0 False
00 False
0101 True
0001 False
010011000111 True
0011010100001111 True

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Edición

El código anterior falla en ciertos casos, y la solución es terminar el proceso tan pronto se sepa que la secuencia no cumple la condición.

La primera condición es que `n` sea negativo, pues significa que el bit actual ha ocurrido más veces que el bit anterior.

La segunda condición se detecta al cambio de 0 <-> 1: Si veníamos decrementando, `n` tiene que ser mayor que cero. Un valor mayor significa que el último bit ocurrio menos veces que el antepenúltimo.

*Código mejorado*

```
def check2(lista):
    n = 0
    if lista:
        inc = 1
        prev = lista[0]
        for bit in lista:
            if bit != prev:
                if inc < 0 and n:
                    break
                inc = -inc
                prev = bit
            n += inc
            if n < 0:
                break
    return n == 0
```

**Demo**

```
tests = [
    "001011",
    "00011011",
    "011111111"
]

for test in tests:
    r1 = check(test)
    r2 = check2(test)
    print(test, r1, r2)
```

produce:

```
001011 True False
00011011 True False
011111111 False False

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Nota** Esta versión retorna true si se encuentran dos secuencias de ceros y de unos de la misma longitud, *aunque no vayan seguidas*. Por ejemplo la cadena "000110111" retornaría True porque hay una secuencia de 3 ceros al inicio y una de 3 unos al final.
>
> No tengo del todo claro si es esto lo que se busca, o si las secuencias han de ir seguidas, en cuyo caso esta solución no sería válida (véase en este caso [la respuesta de @CandidMoe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/493047/7123)). De todas formas me ha parecido interesante proporcionar esta respuesta como un ejemplo de uso de conjuntos para resolver problemas complejos.

```py
import re
def check(cadena):
  ceros = set(len(x) for x in re.findall("0+", cadena))
  unos = set(len(x) for x in re.findall("1+", cadena))
  return bool(ceros & unos)
```

Cómo funciona:

- `re.findall()` aplica una expresión regular y devuelve una lista con todos los *matches* que se hayan producid. La expresión regular usada es `"0+"` que significa una secuencia de ceros seguidos. Por ejemplo, al aplicar esa expresión regular sobre la cadena `"010011000111"` devolvería la lista `["0", "00", "000"]`, pues esas son las secuencias de ceros seguidos que se hallan en la cadena. De forma análoga, usando la expresión regular `"1+"` se detectan secuencias de unos.
- La comprensión `len(x) for x in ...` aplica la operación `len()` a cada elemento resultante de la lista anterior. Así en el ejemplo en que los resultados fueron `["0", "00", "000"]`, las longitudes serán `[1, 2, 3]` Eso nos dice cuántos ceros seguidos hemos encontrado (o unos en el segundo caso).
- La operación `set()` convierte la lista en un conjunto. Esto elimina duplicados. Por ejemplo si la entrada es `"00100"`, el resultado del findall sería `["00", "00"]` y tras aplicar `len()` tendríamos `[2, 2]`. Al convertirlo en conjunto tendríamos ya un solo 2.

  Además, el tenerlo en conjuntos nos permitirá hacer la intersección, que será el paso final.
- `ceros & unos` realiza la intersección entre dos conjuntos. Si por ejemplo el conjunto de los ceros era `{1, 2, 3}` (lo que significa que se han encontrado secuencias con uno, con dos y con tres ceros) y la de unos es `{2, 4}` (lo que significaría que se han encontrado secuencias compuestas de dos y cuatro unos).

  La intersección entre esos conjuntos te deja sólo los números que aparezcan en ambos (`{2}` en el ejemplo anterior).
- La conversión a `bool()` del resultado es lo que buscamos, ya que si el resultado fue el conjunto vacío es que no había secuencias de ceros y unos de la misma longitud, mientras que si el conjunto no es vacío es que sí había. La conversión a booleano hace justamente eso: retorna `False` si el conjunto es vacío o `True` si no.

**Demo**

```py
tests = [
    "",
    "0",
    "00",
    "0101",
    "0001",
    "010011000111",
    "0011010100001111"
]

for test in tests:
  print(repr(test), "--->", check(test))
```

Sale:

```
'' ---> False
'0' ---> False
'00' ---> False
'0101' ---> True
'0001' ---> False
'010011000111' ---> True
'0011010100001111' ---> True
```